# Asp .net treeview , take the value from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have an `ascx control` with a an **ASP.NET** treeview inside. I am trying to take the value from another `ascx control` which is in the same page, with the following method.

```
       var treeViewData = window["<%=TreeView1.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
        if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {
            var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
            var value = selectedNode.href.substring(selectedNode.href.indexOf(",") + 3, selectedNode.href.length - 2);
            var text = selectedNode.innerHTML;
            alert("Text: " + text + "\r\n" + "Value: " + value);
        } else {
            alert("No node selected.")
        }
```

But it cannot find the TreeView1 because it is a different ascx control. Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript variable in you first user control and put

```
var treeViewID = "<%=TreeView1.ClientID%>";
```

And then in you second user control use this JavaScript variable to get the element (JS variables are global)

```
var treeView = window[treeViewID + "_Data"] ;
```

NOTE: For this to work your first control should be rendered before the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global js variable in the aspx page that will be set by the ascx with the tree view after a node was selected, and get this value in the other ascx. Their js code operates together but not their aspx and cs code.